# Can I set breakpoints on package or file level in Intellij Idea?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I am not sure about the implementation used by a bunch of interfaces. Is it possible to set breakpoints on package/class files/external libraries in Idea?

Comment: idea shows class instance on runtime. so you can you check with breakpoint on your instance

Comment: Short answer. No, it is not possible. 
The implementation might even not exist (like for classes generated on the flight). However you can find the implementation  which was invoked using 'Step In/Out' features of IntelliJ. It is hard to achieve if you want to debug code from frameworks like spring or hibernate because they generate a lot on the flight, but it is still possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breakpoint cannot be applied on package or file level and the problem you are facing is very common when you are working on a Enterprise level software.

The workaround is put a breakpoint where you are confused first and hit **Step into (F7 - Intellij)**, the debug control will be transferred to the class/method which is being used currently.